# How to write meter-bus in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

In my studies I have to write meter-bus (m-bus) protocol/functions in VHDL. and I have no idea from which point should I start. I read a little bit of http://www.m-bus.com/mbusdoc/default.php but were is a lot of information. Probably some one of you know the right functions list how should it work, or maybe some one have the example, or information how I should do it?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What layers of the protocol? Targeting what device? More details will help answers of this question. As an aside, if this is really for "studies" and you're asking questions like this, this is likely a incredibly over-ambitious project to tackle. You might want to start with something a little easier and move up from there. =) Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in VHDL, not software?

Comment: @Martin : if it's a simple enough protocol, no need for a CPU. I can't remember mbus well enough to say, but it looked not much more than a RS232 UART. If you only need to send a couple of canned messages, state machine + UART might do.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: true, but that goes against my general principle of 'if it can feasibly be done without an FPGA, then do so' :)  Even if it's a couple of canned messages I think I'd rather do it with an AVR/PIC/etc than an FPGA state machine...

Comment: I was assuming the FPGA had to be there anyway: if it doesn't, that's certainly a lower effort approach.

Comment: I just have to write only m-bus automaton, how should it jump from one state to second state and something like that, i didnt have write network mode, or other dificult metods. just write m-bus autoamaton connected with rs232 (i had writen it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say start from the bottom.

1: Find the necessary transceiver chip (a TSS721 chip according to the physical layer documentation), and get it hooked up to an FPGA. You can probably do a loopback with it, and just try sending and receiving data from the same FPGA.
Interfacing to it seems to be done through a UART, so you can either write one yourself, or use one of the many UART implementations available (if you are using Xilinx Spartan-series or similar, have a look at the [PicoBlaze UART implementation](http://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/picoblaze.htm)).

2: Once the physical layer is working (either as loopback on a single FPGA, or between two FPGAs), carry on with the next layer (the Datalink-layer) and get that working. I can highly recommend familiarizing yourself with a good simulator, which will allow you to test out the layers one by one, instead of having to rely on in-target tests in the FPGA.

3: Proceed to the next layers (Application and Network), until you're done.

For reference, I built something similar during my master thesis - a custom-made FPGA-based network, using Toslink transceivers. The project can be found [here](http://opencores.org/project,tosnet), and the code [here](http://opencores.org/websvn,listing?repname=tosnet&path=/tosnet/trunk/gateware/TosNet_rev3_2/#path_tosnet_trunk_gateware_TosNet_rev3_2_) - if you're interested in the full thesis, I can probably dig up the pdf's somewhere...

Comment: I just have to write only m-bus automaton, how should it jump from one state to second state and something like that